# How does one pronounce the sefardi Ayin?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters

I was taught how to read in an ashekenazi yeshivah where no difference was made between the aleph and ayin. I keep trying to make my ayin gutteral but it never sounds exactly how the sephardim pronounce it. Is there a specific technique I can use to get the right sound. What can I do to practice pronouncing this letter?

The intention behind this question is so that I would be able to read the daily prayers accurately according to my tradition.

Comment: It'd help with the correct pronunciation of your username, too! (Not to mention that of your favorite online community.)

Comment: I recommend [Ladefoged](/a/10254).

Answer (score 2):

The correct pronunciation is a pharyngealized glottal stop. The best way to learn to pronounce this letter is to learn how to properly learn how to pronounce a Teth (ט) first. This is a pharyngealized voiceless alveolar stop. To make this sound, make your tongue into a cup. It should be pressing on your furthest back top molars. You should also feel an uncomfortable sensation in your throat, which might cause you to gag a little until you get used to it. Keeping your tongue in this shape, say 'Ta'. It'll come out sounding odd, and half way between a T and D. Once you can do that easily, you're ready to try an Ayin. The glottal stop is the sound you probably don't hear that occurs at the beginning of all the words that start with a vowel sound. It's easiest to hear the sound as the '-' in 'uh-oh'. Make your tongue into the bowl shape and say 'oh'. It will sound weird again in the same way as the Teth. That's an Ayin. Practice 'uh'-'Oh' until you sound like a Yemenite.

Comment: I'm pretty sure glottal stop is silence caused by the glottis and so I'm not sure its proper to call ayin a glottal stop, when aleph is a glottal stop

Comment: @Aaron Pharyngealization is a secondary articulation that makes it a different letter. All the emphatic letters can be thought of as pharyngealized other letters. Teth is a pharyngealized taw, Sadhi is a pharyngealized Samekh, Qaf is a pharyngealized Kaph, Heth can be thought of as a pharyngealized Heh. Ayin is a pharyngealized Aleph. The constriction of the throat prevents total closure of the glottis, and the secondary articulation colors the following vowel, which is enough to make it it's own letter.

Comment: Still not comfortable with the term glottal stop as again it refers to the idea that you stop all airflow and it creates a break in sound. i understand what you are referring to, and how maybe you mean you approach a glottal stop.  But whatever. It's your description.

Comment: @Aaron You do stop all airflow. The IPA is [ʔˤ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayin#Phonetic_representation).

Comment: No, there are several possible IPAs for it as there are a few ways to do Ayin. There is ʕ, ʢ, and ʔˤ. You can pronounce the Ayin in any of those ways. There are those who do a type of glottal stop, i myself do it for emphasis on occasion. But ayin can be made without a full stoppage, or in other words, a voiced pharyngeal approximant or fricative.

Comment: @Aaron Those three are from the link I posted. The link also says the fricative or approximant is not actually attested in Hebrew. This is true. I have listened to recordings of chanting and there is clearly always a stop. I have only heard the fricative among non native speakers and it appears to be an Arabic corruption. The same for an IPA for epiglotal trill, where Arabic uses the epiglottal fricative, that's where the fricative is sometimes used. However, the majority case that doesn't occur in Arabic is the pharyngealizes glottal stop.

Comment: @Aaron it also makes more sense from a historical perspective. In antiquity, it was noted that ayin and aleph sound similar. A fricative does not sound like a stop. And the ayin always merges with an aleph, where you would expect to a see a fricative merge with a heth, which never happens.

Comment: This could go on and on forever. i've heard noted Sephardi Chazzanim such as Moshe Chabusha pronounce Ayin as a fricative, rather than a stop. And i don't know what it is you are speaking of that in Antiquity the Ayin and the Aleph sound similar. i know that there were those who did not distinguish between Aleph and Ayin, but it could be that they didn't sound out either. We don't know in what way they were similar to those people then. Either way, i think it's a disservice to say "an ayin is only this" when from my experience people do Ayins very differently, from a fricative to a stop

Comment: @Aaron It's probably not worth a back and forth without sources to back it up, I agree. The only source cited says it's unattested in Hebrew, but this stuff fascinates me and I'd love if you could hunt down a counter source. I haven't noticed Moshe Chabusha use a fricative. I just listened to the first video that popped up on youtube, החזן משה חבושה בהופעה בארהב. It's hard to tell from the quality of the recording if he's consistent, but there were instances where it is unambiguously a stop, so I wouldn't use this as an unequivocal example of a fricative.

Comment: It's been my experience that depending on where the Ayin falls has a lot to do with what causes it to be a stop or not. The vowels that come before or after it, or whether it is at the start or end of a word. i've also read that linguists believe there were two ayins in antiquity, as we have evidence that when the bible as translated into Greek and other languages, the letter Ayin would be transliterated as a hard G in some instances, and sometimes the letter would be ignored and only the vowel would be translated. Which is why the septuagint has sodom and Gomorrah.

Comment: @Aaron I think word context has less to do with proper pronunciation, and more to do with difficulty in articulating correctly. But I've been doing some research, and it's no longer believed that the fricative occurs even in arabic, and it's now being taught as a stop there as well. The ghain pronunciation for ayin is a different letter that's been lost. Like the Shin and Sin distinction, but just no longer preserved. This is most obvious in רע, the evil translation probably being a ghain, and the friend translation being an ayin, but also in עיר, יעל, and רעה. This is preserved in arabic.

Comment: The glottal stop is the sound of the two t's in "button", the way most of us really say it when not thinking about needing a /t/ sound.